# Create an index, or add to the primary key and create a new table?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, database, nosql

In Cassandra, I have a table with columns `(a,b,c)`. I either need to query `SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE a = ? and b = ?` and `SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE a = ? and c = ?`.

In this case, what should I make the primary key? Could I make two tables with `PRIMARY KEY(a,b)` and `PRIMARY KEY(a,c)`, because Cassandra needs the entirety of the partition key and/or non-partition keys in the order they are listed? Or could I do something like `PRIMARY KEY(a)` and create an `INDEX` on `b` and `c`?

Basically, should the primary key only contain the minimum number of values required for uniqueness (and choosing an appropriate partition key from these values)? Will performance improve if I add other columns to the primary key because I need to query them?

Comment: It is difficult to answer, `with the information that you have provided`. Please edit your complete schema and column cardinality detail to investigate more. Only with those information, schema can be analyzed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above, a well-grounded answer can only be given if you provide more information about the cardinality of the a, b and c columns. Also make sure you understand the meaning of partitioning key and clustering key - they are both part of primary key, and have a huge impact on your design.

If you have enough distinct values in column a, you can make it a partition key, and choose one from the following two approaches:

1) separate table for each query

```
CREATE TABLE table1_by_ab (
  a int, b int, c int, 
  PRIMARY KEY (a, b));

CREATE TABLE table1_by_ac (
  a int, b int, c int, 
  PRIMARY KEY (a, c));
```

2) one table for the more frequent query, and index for the other column:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  a int, b int, c int, 
  PRIMARY KEY (a, b));

CREATE INDEX ON table2 (c);
```

In both cases you can execute your queries on (a,b) and (a,c). Usually it is recommended to avoid secondary indexes, but in case 2) your query on (a,c) pre-selects the partition key (field a), so the secondary index can be executed on a single node, and its performance will not be bad.

If you don't have enough distinct values in column a, then you cannot make it a partitioning key, you will need to duplicate your tables, both with a compound partitioning key:

```
CREATE TABLE table3_by_ab (
  a int, b int, c int, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((a, b)));

CREATE TABLE table3_by_ac (
  a int, b int, c int, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((a, c)));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So in general, it's okay to create a new table for each query, as I've seen several times on SO? For example, consider if this situation were expanded to a table with five parameters that are queried in different orders. Would it be okay to create several (3-4) tables with the same information, but with different primary keys, to suit these queries?

Comment: One last question: is there a difference between querying `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE a =  ? and b = ? and c = ?` with `PRIMARY KEY(a,b,c)` or with `PRIMARY KEY(a,b)` and an `INDEX` on `c`?

Comment: Duplicating tables is fine in Cassandra, because writes are very fast and disk space is cheap. However 3-4 tables for the same data could also be a sign for wrong model or use case which is not really suitable for Cassandra.

Comment: Querying by primary key is always faster. Secondary indexes have an overhead both on writing and reading. Their performance is better if the partition key is pre-filtered, but still they need to maintained and need to be accessed. On the other hand they are more convenient to use, so I suggest to create a PoC and measure.